# How do I enable front and back camera on Android Studio Virtual Device?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

I'm using an AVD on Android Studio. The app I'm using performs verification, first taking a photo with the back camera, and then switching to the front camera to take a selfie. But the problem I'm having is that I can't seem to use both cameras. Whichever one I don't assign "webcam0" shows a black screen. To get the front facing camera to work for the selfie, I need to assign "webcam0" and either "emulate" or "virtualscreen" to the back. But then the back camera doesn't work.

How do I get both to work? I really need to be able to take a photo with the front and back camera. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can't generally use both cameras at once.  There may be some devices where it's possible, but generally they share hardware resources on the motherboard.  The only way to do this reliably is to take the pictures one at a time and release the Camera object between them.